# How to fix or remove Solr configuration?

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to set up Solr on RHEL as a better search engine for Drupal and admittedly I don't really know what I'm doing. I've installed Solr and am now trying to create a core. While crafting the URL, I accidently clicked on it and now I have a unusable configuration. I'm getting this error:

```
ylncore-name: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load conf for core ylncore-name: Error loading solr config from /var/solr/data/path/to/dir/conf/solrconfig.xml
```

I deleted the core via the dashboard and from the command line which didn't help. I've grepped across the drive for files with the path but can't find any. Web searching makes it sound like I have to do something with Zookeeper but I don't know what. How do I fix or delete the config so that I can start over?

Comment: check if you have solr.xml file and it has the entry...you may need to correct it

Comment: Couple of things to try: Try to stop and restart Solr from the command line (with `solr stop` and `solr start`). Close the browser window with the Solr Admin web page and re-open it (the page does some client-side fancy thing that something keeps displaying errors when they are not longer relevant.) The other option would be to stop solr, delete the folder with the bad core (it should be under solr/server/solr/your-core), and restart solr.

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti The solr.xml file didn't have any paths in it.

Comment: @HectorCorrea Thank you so much for the info. I restarted Solr and restarted the browser. The error went away. Then I set the core up again from scratch and it worked!